# What could be causing Android (Kotlin) Fragments visual glitchs (fragments overlap on nagivate)?

Tags: android, kotlin, generics, android-fragments, fragment

I have a fragments displaying lists of items and it's forms to populate the lists.
When i go to the list fragment to the form fragment using `findNavController().navigate()` the form fragment is shown only on the 50% of the screen, after a couple seconds it finishs showing the other 50%. If i scroll the screen the fragments shows it´s 100% instantly, if i idle and do not touch the screen it takes several seconds.
In some of the fragment transacction the glitch is not random, meaning i can reproduce it every time i make that `findNavController().navigate()`.
But there are other cases where the glitch happens sometimes and some other times it does not.

This is happening in emulator and in real devices also.

This is how it looks like (this is the one i can reproduce) [image: here]
[image: Another example]
[image: 3rd example]

This is how i nav from list fragment to form fragment. Backwards i use the generated backwards button at the left top corner.

```
    findNavController().navigate(
        R.id.nav_form_automovil,
        args = b
    )
```

I may add that i am using abstract generic clases that i created to reutilize code. The glitchs started happening around that time.

```
abstract class BaseListItemFragment<T, B : ViewBinding, F : BaseFormState>(@LayoutRes id: Int) :
    BaseItemFragment<T, B, F>(id) {
    private var _recyclerView: RecyclerView? = null
    private var _adapter: BaseAdapter<T>? = null

    fun initRecycler(recyclerView: RecyclerView, adapter: BaseAdapter<T>) {
        _recyclerView = recyclerView
        _recyclerView?.layoutManager =
            LinearLayoutManager(
                MainApplication.instance.applicationContext,
                LinearLayoutManager.VERTICAL,
                false
            )
        _adapter = adapter
        _recyclerView?.adapter = _adapter
    }

    private fun observeItemList() =
        viewModel?.itemList?.observe(viewLifecycleOwner, Observer {
            val itemList = it ?: return@Observer
            viewModel?.updateIsLoading(false)
            if (itemList.isNotEmpty()) {
                _adapter?.updateModels(itemList)
                _recyclerView?.smoothScrollToPosition(0)
            }
        })

    override fun onViewCreated(view: View, savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onViewCreated(view, savedInstanceState)
        observeItemList()
    }

    override fun onResume() {
        super.onResume()
        viewModel?.fetchAndObserve()
    }
}


abstract class BaseItemFragment<T, B : ViewBinding, F : BaseFormState>(@LayoutRes id: Int) :
    Fragment(id) {
    private var _binding: B? = null
    val binding get() = _binding
    var viewModel: BaseItemViewModel<T, F>? = null

    fun inflateLayout(viewBinding: B) {
        _binding = viewBinding
    }

    override fun onDestroyView() {
        super.onDestroyView()
        _binding = null
    }

    override fun onCreateView(
        inflater: LayoutInflater,
        container: ViewGroup?,
        savedInstanceState: Bundle?
    ): View? {
        provideViewModels()
        return super.onCreateView(inflater, container, savedInstanceState)
    }

    override fun onViewCreated(view: View, savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onViewCreated(view, savedInstanceState)
        enableLoadingScreen()
        observeLogoutFlag()
        setUpListeners(view)
    }

    private fun observeLogoutFlag() =
        viewModel?.refreshTokenExpired?.observe(viewLifecycleOwner, Observer {
            val isExpired = it ?: return@Observer
            if (isExpired) {
                activity?.finish()
            }
        })

    abstract fun enableLoadingScreen()
    abstract fun setUpListeners(view: View)
    abstract fun provideViewModels()

    //**  Extension functions start here  **//
    /**
     * Extension function to simplify setting an afterTextChanged action to EditText components.
     */
    fun EditText.afterTextChanged(afterTextChanged: (String) -> Unit) {
        this.addTextChangedListener(object : TextWatcher {
            override fun afterTextChanged(editable: Editable?) {
                afterTextChanged.invoke(editable.toString())
            }

            override fun beforeTextChanged(s: CharSequence, start: Int, count: Int, after: Int) {}
            override fun onTextChanged(s: CharSequence, start: Int, before: Int, count: Int) {}
        })
    }

    fun Int.toDp(context: Context): Int = TypedValue.applyDimension(
        TypedValue.COMPLEX_UNIT_DIP, this.toFloat(), context.resources.displayMetrics
    ).toInt()
}
```

Provided a viewModel instance my fragments usually performs 1 or 2 or 3 network operations with IO dispatcher, most common case

```
override fun onResume() {
    super.onResume()
    viewModel?.fetchAndObserve()
}
```

Implementations look like this.

```
class AutomovilListFragment() :
    BaseListItemFragment<Automovil, FragmentListAutomovilBinding, AutomovilFormState>(
        R.layout.fragment_list_automovil
    ) {
override fun onCreateView(
        inflater: LayoutInflater,
        container: ViewGroup?,
        savedInstanceState: Bundle?
    ): View {
        super.onCreateView(inflater, container, savedInstanceState)
        inflateLayout(FragmentListAutomovilBinding.inflate(inflater, container, false))
        initRecycler(
            binding!!.listAuto,
            AutomovilAdapter(ArrayList(), WeakReference(this))
        )
        return binding!!.root
    }

    override fun setUpListeners(view: View) {

    }

    override fun enableLoadingScreen() {
        viewModel?.isLoading?.observe(viewLifecycleOwner, Observer {
            val isLoading = it ?: return@Observer
            if (isLoading) binding!!.pBarListAutomovil.visibility = View.VISIBLE
            else binding!!.pBarListAutomovil.visibility = View.INVISIBLE
        })
    }

    override fun provideViewModels() {
        viewModel =
            ViewModelProvider(
                requireActivity(),
                AutomovilViewModelFactory()
            )[AutomovilViewModel::class.java]
    }
}
```

Do anyone see what could be the root cause of this and what route take to find a solution?

EDIT: Added Example Layout, Navigation XML, Build Gradle Files and Manifests

Example Layout:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context="com.qsafe.appKmm.android.ui.fragment.automovil.AutomovilListFragment">

    <androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView
        android:id="@+id/listAuto"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

    <androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout
        android:id="@+id/pBarListAutomovil"
        style="@style/Theme.qsafe.loading.TranslucentBackground"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_marginStart="0sp"
        android:layout_marginTop="0sp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="0sp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="0sp"
        android:clickable="true"
        android:focusable="true"
        android:visibility="invisible"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent">

        <ProgressBar
            android:id="@+id/progressBarListAutomovil"
            style="@android:style/Widget.Holo.ProgressBar.Large"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />
    </androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

Android Manifest:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    package="com.qsafe.appKmm.android">

    <supports-screens
        android:anyDensity="false"
        android:largeScreens="true"
        android:normalScreens="true"
        android:resizeable="true"
        android:smallScreens="true"
        android:xlargeScreens="true" />

    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />

    <application
        android:name="com.qsafe.appKmm.android.MainApplication"
        android:icon="@drawable/qsafe_logo_sin_texto"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:supportsRtl="true"
        android:theme="@style/Theme.qsafe.residente"
        android:usesCleartextTraffic="true"
        tools:targetApi="s">
        <activity
            android:name="com.qsafe.appKmm.android.ui.MainActivity"
            android:configChanges="orientation"
            android:label="Inicio"
            android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustResize" />
        <activity
            android:name="com.qsafe.appKmm.android.login.LoginActivity"
            android:configChanges="orientation"
            android:exported="true"
            android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustResize" />
        <activity
            android:name="com.qsafe.appKmm.android.login.LoginSplashActivity"
            android:exported="true">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.BROWSABLE" />

                <data
                    android:host="sistema.qsafe.mx"
                    android:pathPattern="/Account/Login"
                    android:scheme="http" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
        <activity
            android:name="com.qsafe.appKmm.android.login.pass.PassForgotActivity"
            android:exported="true"
            android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustPan">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.BROWSABLE" />

                <data
                    android:host="sistema.qsafe.mx"
                    android:pathPattern="/Account/ForgotPassword"
                    android:scheme="http" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
        <activity
            android:name="com.qsafe.appKmm.android.login.pass.PassResetActivity"
            android:exported="true"
            android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustPan">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.BROWSABLE" />

                <data
                    android:host="sistema.qsafe.mx"
                    android:pathPattern="/Account/ResetPassword"
                    android:scheme="http" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>

        <service
            android:name="com.qsafe.appKmm.android.com.qsafe.appkmm.android.MyFirebaseMessagingService"
            android:exported="false">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="com.google.firebase.MESSAGING_EVENT" />
            </intent-filter>
        </service>
        <meta-data
            android:name="com.google.firebase.messaging.default_notification_icon"
            android:resource="@drawable/qsafe_logo_sin_texto" />
        
        <meta-data
            android:name="com.google.firebase.messaging.default_notification_color"
            android:resource="@color/cardview_light_background" />

        <provider
            android:name="androidx.startup.InitializationProvider"
            android:authorities="${applicationId}.androidx-startup"
            android:exported="false"
            tools:node="merge">
            <meta-data
                android:name="appKmm.appKmm.MySqlDelightInitializer"
                tools:node="remove" />
        </provider>


    </application>

</manifest>
```

App Build gradle

```
plugins {
    //trick: for the same plugin versions in all sub-modules
    id("com.android.application").version("7.2.0").apply(false)
    id("com.android.library").version("7.2.0").apply(false)
    kotlin("android").version("1.7.10").apply(false)
    kotlin("multiplatform").version("1.7.10").apply(false)
}

buildscript {
    repositories {
        gradlePluginPortal()
        google()
        mavenCentral()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath("org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-gradle-plugin:1.7.10")
        classpath("com.android.tools.build:gradle:7.1.3")
        classpath("com.google.gms:google-services:4.3.14")
        classpath("org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-serialization:1.7.10")
        classpath("com.squareup.sqldelight:gradle-plugin:1.5.3")
    }
}

allprojects {
    repositories {
        google()
        mavenCentral()
        maven {
            setUrl("https://oss.sonatype.org/content/repositories/snapshots/")
        }
        maven {
            setUrl("https://jitpack.io")
        }
    }
}

tasks.register("clean", Delete::class) {
    delete(rootProject.buildDir)
}
```

Android Build Gradle:

```
plugins {
    id("com.android.application")
    id("com.google.gms.google-services")
    kotlin("android")
    id("kotlin-android-extensions")
}
android {
    compileSdk = 32
    defaultConfig {
        applicationId = "com.qsafe.appKmm.android"
        minSdk = 26
        targetSdk = 32
        versionCode = 3
        versionName = "3"
    }
    buildTypes {
        getByName("release") {
            isMinifyEnabled = true
        }
    }
    kotlinOptions {
        jvmTarget = "1.8"
    }
    buildFeatures {
        viewBinding = true
        dataBinding = true
    }
    compileOptions {
        sourceCompatibility = JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
        targetCompatibility = JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
    }
}

dependencies {
    //QUADRO
    implementation(project(":shared"))
    //ANDROIDX
    implementation("androidx.fragment:fragment-ktx:1.5.3")
    implementation("androidx.appcompat:appcompat:1.5.1")
    implementation("androidx.navigation:navigation-fragment-ktx:2.5.2")
    //implementation("androidx.constraintlayout:constraintlayout:2.1.4")
    implementation("androidx.navigation:navigation-ui-ktx:2.5.2")
    implementation("androidx.legacy:legacy-support-v4:1.0.0")
    implementation("androidx.recyclerview:recyclerview:1.2.1")
    implementation("androidx.lifecycle:lifecycle-viewmodel-ktx:2.5.1")
    implementation("androidx.lifecycle:lifecycle-livedata-ktx:2.5.1")
    implementation("androidx.work:work-runtime-ktx:2.7.1")
    implementation("androidx.security:security-crypto:1.1.0-alpha03")
    //JETBRAINS
    implementation("org.jetbrains.kotlinx:kotlinx-coroutines-core:1.6.1")
    implementation("org.jetbrains.kotlinx:kotlinx-coroutines-android:1.6.1")
    //GOOGLE
    implementation("com.google.android.material:material:1.6.1")
    implementation("com.google.code.gson:gson:2.9.0")
    // Add the dependencies for any other desired Firebase products
    // https://firebase.google.com/docs/android/setup#available-libraries
    implementation("com.google.firebase:firebase-core:21.1.1")
    implementation("com.google.firebase:firebase-messaging-ktx:23.0.8")
    implementation("com.google.firebase:firebase-common-ktx:20.1.2")
    implementation("com.google.firebase:firebase-analytics-ktx:21.1.1")
    //SQUAREUP
    implementation("com.squareup.retrofit2:retrofit:2.9.0")
    implementation("com.squareup.retrofit2:converter-gson:2.9.0")
    implementation("com.squareup.okhttp3:okhttp:3.14.9")
    implementation("com.squareup.okhttp3:logging-interceptor:3.14.0")

    //TOASTY
    implementation ("com.github.GrenderG:Toasty:1.5.2")

}
```

Shared Module KMM build gradle:

```
import org.jetbrains.kotlin.gradle.plugin.mpp.KotlinNativeTarget

val ktor_version = "2.0.1"
val coroutines_version = "1.6.0"
val kotlinx_serialization_version = "1.3.2"
val sqldelight_version = "1.5.3"
val arkitekt_version = "0.1.1-SNAPSHOT"

plugins {
    id("com.android.library")
    id("com.squareup.sqldelight")
    kotlin("multiplatform")
    kotlin("plugin.serialization")
    kotlin("native.cocoapods")
}
version = "1.0"
sqldelight {
    database("CommonDatabase") {
        packageName = "com.qsafe.appKmm.db"
        sourceFolders = listOf("sqldelight")
    }
}

kotlin {
    android()

    val iosTarget: (String, KotlinNativeTarget.() -> Unit) -> KotlinNativeTarget =
        if (System.getenv("SDK_NAME")?.startsWith("iphoneos") == true)
            ::iosArm64
        else
            ::iosX64

    iosTarget("ios") {}


    cocoapods {
        summary = "Some description for the Shared Module"
        homepage = "Link to the Shared Module homepage"
        ios.deploymentTarget = "12.4"
        framework {
            baseName = "shared"
        }
        podfile = project.file("../Qsafe/Podfile")
    }

    sourceSets {

        val commonMain by getting {
            dependencies {
                // Coroutines
                implementation("org.jetbrains.kotlinx:kotlinx-coroutines-core:$coroutines_version")
                // Serialization
                implementation("org.jetbrains.kotlinx:kotlinx-serialization-core:$kotlinx_serialization_version")
                implementation("org.jetbrains.kotlinx:kotlinx-serialization-json:$kotlinx_serialization_version")
                // Ktor
                implementation("io.ktor:ktor-client-core:$ktor_version")
                implementation("io.ktor:ktor-client-auth:$ktor_version")
                implementation("io.ktor:ktor-client-json:$ktor_version")
                implementation("io.ktor:ktor-client-serialization:$ktor_version")
                implementation("io.ktor:ktor-client-content-negotiation:$ktor_version")
                implementation("io.ktor:ktor-serialization-kotlinx-json:$ktor_version")
                implementation("io.ktor:ktor-client-logging:$ktor_version")
                // SqlDelight
                implementation("com.squareup.sqldelight:runtime:$sqldelight_version")
                implementation("com.squareup.sqldelight:coroutines-extensions:$sqldelight_version")
                // Arkitekt
                api("app.futured.arkitekt:km-usecases:$arkitekt_version")
                implementation(kotlin("script-runtime"))
                //Kodein dependency injection
                implementation("org.kodein.di:kodein-di:7.10.0")
            }
        }
        val commonTest by getting {
            dependencies {
                implementation(kotlin("test-common"))
                implementation(kotlin("test-annotations-common"))
            }
        }
        val androidMain by getting {
            dependencies {
                // Ktor android engine
                implementation("io.ktor:ktor-client-android:$ktor_version")
                // SqlDelight android driver
                implementation("com.squareup.sqldelight:android-driver:$sqldelight_version")
                //App Startup
                implementation("androidx.startup:startup-runtime:1.1.1")
            }
        }
        val androidTest by getting {
            dependencies {
                implementation(kotlin("test-junit"))
                implementation("junit:junit:4.13.2")
            }
        }
        val iosMain by getting {
            dependencies {
                // Ktor ios engine
                implementation("io.ktor:ktor-client-ios:$ktor_version")
                // SqlDelight iOS driver
                implementation("com.squareup.sqldelight:native-driver:$sqldelight_version")
                // Arkitekt viewmodel
                api("app.futured.arkitekt:km-viewmodel:0.1.2-SNAPSHOT")
            }
        }
        val iosTest by getting
    }
}
android {
    compileSdk = 32
    sourceSets["main"].manifest.srcFile("src/androidMain/AndroidManifest.xml")
    defaultConfig {
        minSdk = 24
        targetSdk = 32
    }
}
```

Navigation XML file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<navigation xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/mobile_navigation"
    app:startDestination="@+id/nav_bitacora">

    <fragment
        android:id="@+id/nav_bitacora"
        android:name="com.qsafe.appKmm.android.ui.fragment.bitacora.BitacoraListFragment"
        android:label="Inicio"
        app:enterAnim="@android:anim/fade_in"
        app:exitAnim="@android:anim/fade_out"
        app:popEnterAnim="@anim/nav_default_pop_enter_anim"
        app:popExitAnim="@anim/nav_default_pop_exit_anim"
        tools:layout="@layout/fragment_list_bitacora">
        <action
            android:id="@+id/action_nav_bitacora_to_nav_settings"
            app:destination="@id/nav_settings"
            app:enterAnim="@android:anim/fade_in"
            app:exitAnim="@android:anim/fade_out"
            app:popEnterAnim="@anim/nav_default_pop_enter_anim"
            app:popExitAnim="@anim/nav_default_pop_exit_anim" />
        <action
            android:id="@+id/action_nav_bitacora_to_nav_automoviles"
            app:destination="@id/nav_automovil"
            app:enterAnim="@android:anim/fade_in"
            app:exitAnim="@android:anim/fade_out"
            app:popEnterAnim="@anim/nav_default_pop_enter_anim"
            app:popExitAnim="@anim/nav_default_pop_exit_anim" />
        <action

    <fragment
        android:id="@+id/nav_automovil"
        android:name="com.qsafe.appKmm.android.ui.fragment.automovil.AutomovilListFragment"
        android:label="Automóviles"
        tools:layout="@layout/fragment_list_automovil">
        <action
            android:id="@+id/action_nav_automovil_to_nav_form_automovil"
            app:destination="@id/nav_form_automovil"
            app:enterAnim="@android:anim/fade_in"
            app:exitAnim="@android:anim/fade_out"
            app:popEnterAnim="@anim/nav_default_pop_enter_anim"
            app:popExitAnim="@anim/nav_default_pop_exit_anim" />
    </fragment>

    <fragment
        android:id="@+id/nav_form_automovil"
        android:name="com.qsafe.appKmm.android.ui.fragment.automovil.FormAutomovilFragment"
        android:label="Guardar automóvil"
        tools:layout="@layout/fragment_form_automovil">
        <action
            android:id="@+id/action_nav_form_automovil_to_nav_automovil"
            app:destination="@id/nav_automovil"
            app:enterAnim="@android:anim/fade_in"
            app:exitAnim="@android:anim/fade_out"
            app:popEnterAnim="@anim/nav_default_pop_enter_anim"
            app:popExitAnim="@anim/nav_default_pop_exit_anim" />
    </fragment>
.... some more fragment navigations ...
</navigation>
```

Comment: Provide more information about libs versions, xml of Fragment where it happened and do you use transaction animation?

Comment: @Yuriy i added them! I am not using animations, that i know only on one fragment to test it and the glitch now is eased out by the animation but still blink a random white square for a second.

Comment: BTW i just droped the basecode and switched to an hybrid development using ionic, mainly decided to opt in for that framework in an attempt to speed up development after losing so much time with the KMM project. 
Still accepting answers if someone find one.